# Hang within chapter caption (within document and table of contents (if necessary))

Tags: table-of-contents, indentation, chapters

Usually, long chapter headings look like this:

```
Chapter 1

This is a very long chapter heading; it is so long that is has a line break, but that’s
okay
```

Now, I would like to change it the following way (within the document as well as in the table of contents (if necessary)):

```
Chapter 2

Attention: This is also a very long chapter heading, but now, I would like it to continue
           after "Attention: ".
```

Another example:

```
Chapter 3

A: This is a very long chapter heading; but now, I would like to continue after "A: " so
   that it looks like this.
```

Using `\\\phantom{Attention: }` does not work.

Full code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=false,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = T1}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{hanging}
\newlength{\hangwidth}
\newcommand{\myhang}[1]{\settowidth{\hangwidth}{#1}\hangpara{\hangwidth}{1}#1}
\geometry{
    left=2cm,
    right=2cm,
    top=2cm,
    bottom=2cm,
    bindingoffset=0mm
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \vspace*{2cm}
        \centering
        {\scshape\LARGE Title page\par}
    \end{titlepage}

    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \tableofcontents

    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \chapter{This is a very long caption; I do not care about line breaks here}
    \chapter{Attention: Here, I definitely care about line breaks; even within the table of contents}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are various ways to obtain this, but you should post  a minimal example of what you've tried, that we can play with.

Comment: How should that be obtained? Only if there is a ":" in the heading? Or every time for the first word? Or with a constant width and for every heading?

Comment: @Skillmon I would like to have no line break in the caption of the first chapter. In the second chapter, I would like to have a line break with hang after `Attention: `. If there is a third chapter where I also care about line breaking that does not have something like `Attention: ` in front of the caption but something like `A: `, I would like it to have a line break with hang after `A: `. A `:` is not a must. It just happens to be there and depicts the start of the line break with hang. But it should not be necessary.

Comment: And how should the syntax be, if you want an arbitrary symbol (or no symbol) to indicate the width of the hang?

Comment: @Skillmon I don’t know what you exactly mean. I do not want a symbol to indicate a line break with hang. I would like to set it after whatever portion of text I choose. So, a line break with hang may either occur after something like `Attention: ` or `Attention: This ` or anything else. I would like to set the line break with hang wherever I want with no particular character indicating it (if that is possible).

Comment: No, it is not possible without any syntax. There has to be something that tells LaTeX how long the hanging indent should be. In the accepted answer this syntax works with using two arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `\hangindent` has to be used before the start of the paragraph, I used a `\parbox` instead.  The tricky bit was getting the page number to line up with the bottom instead of the top.  Because the TOC entry is written to the AUX file, I passed the formatting instructions as `\string\hangtoc`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=false,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = T1}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{
    left=2cm,
    right=2cm,
    top=2cm,
    bottom=2cm,
    bindingoffset=0mm
}

\newcommand{\hangtitle}[2]% #1=text for hang, #2=rest of title
 {\sbox0{#1}\usebox0\parbox[t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd0}{\raggedright#2\strut}}

\newcommand{\hangtoc}[2]% #1=text for hang, #2=rest of title
 {\sbox0{#1}\usebox0%
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd0-\leftskip-\rightskip}{\raggedright#2\strut}%
  \vspace{-\baselineskip}\linebreak\hspace*{\fill}}

\newcommand{\mychapter}[2]% #1=text for hang, #2=rest of title
  {\chapter[\string\hangtoc{#1}{#2}]{\hangtitle{#1}{#2}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        \vspace*{2cm}
        \centering
        {\scshape\LARGE Title page\par}
    \end{titlepage}

    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{Roman}
    \tableofcontents

    \cleardoublepage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}

    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \chapter{This is a very long caption; I do not care about line breaks here}
    \mychapter{Attention: }{Here, I definitely care about line breaks; even within the table of contents}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very good! It works. But the chapter heading is now justified. I prevent it with the help of ```\\```.

Comment: There is still one minor problem: If I prevent justified captions with the help of ```\\```, this will, of course, also be adjusted in the table of contents. `\mychapter[Attention: Caption]{Attention: }{Caption}` does not work.

Comment: Nah, I just didn't realize the default was \raggedright.

Comment: I have tried to edit the `\mychapter`-function so that it would take four arguments (the other two are for the two elements of the table of contents). This resulted in the desired formatting for the table of contents, but the caption has now been displayed twice within the document. Just adding another ```{\sbox0{#3}\usebox0\parbox[t]{\dimexpr \textwidth-\wd0}{\raggedright#4\strut}}``` won’t do.

Comment: I rearranged things to make it more flexible.  All the work is now done by `\hangtitle` and `\hangtoc`.  To use a "short title" one can write `\chapter[\string\hangtoc{...}{...}]{\hangtitle{...}{...}}`.